# How should I refactor subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am aware of three ways of writing subqueries into a query.

- Normal subquery
- With clause
- Temporary table

Subqueries get extremely messy when there are multiples of them in a query, and especially when you have nested subqueries.

With clause is my preference, but you can only use the subqueries in a WITH clause in the select statement which directly follows the WITH clause (I believe).

Temporary tables are good, but they require quite a bit of over head in declaring the table.

Are there any other ways to refactor subqueries other than these?
And are there any trade offs between them that I haven't considered?

Comment: You can do more than select from a CTE, but yes they are only good for a single statement.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Comment: Well I was just asking about subqueries in general, and I think that they all have subqueries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are leaving out some other capabilities.

The most obvious is views.  If you have a complex query that is going to be used multiple times -- particularly one that might be implementing business rules between tables -- then a view is very useful.  If performance is an issue, then you can materialize the view.

A common use of subqueries is to generate additional columns in a table -- such as the difference between two columns.  You can use computed columns for these calculations, and make them part of the data definition.

Finally, you could implement user-defined functions.  user-defined table-valued functions are a lot like views with parameters.  This can be really helpful under some circumstances.  And the underlying queries should generally be quite optimized.

Another type of user-defined functions are scalar functions.  These usually incur more overhead, but can be quite useful at times.

All that said, if you structure your queries cleanly, then subqueries and CTEs won't look "messy".  You might actually find that you can write very long queries that make sense both to you and to other people reading them.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of preference and readability more than performance, `with` is probably the best.

I don't know which database you are using, but in Oracle the `with` create a [temporary view/table accessible with the name on the LHS of the `as`](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/with-clause) and is not really distinct from a subquery: this name may be used like it were a normal table.

The `select * from (select * from a)` is doing the same: the only matter is that you can not reuse that result:

```
select * from (subquery1) q left join t1 on t1.id = q.id
union all
select * from (subquery1) q left join t2 on t2.id = q.id;
```

But that is where the query plan is important: `subquery1` is the same in both case and the plan may be one that use a temporary table/view, thus reducing the cost of whole.

The `with` is ultimately a way to create temporary table/view and also force the plan optimizer to build query in some order which may (not) be best.

Temporary table would be good if you know the result would be reused later, not in the same query (in which case the `with` does the same work, given the temporary table it use) and even transaction (example: saving the result of a search):

```
begin
  insert into tmp (...); 
  select * from tmp q left join t1 on t1.id = q.id;
  select * from tmp q left join t2 on t2.id = q.id;
end;
```

The `tmp` table is used twice in the same transaction but not in the same query: your database won't recompute the result twice and it is probably fine if all you are doing are `select` (no mutation on `tmp` source).